# ModelState Validation - actionresult is firing twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

I have a checkout page which submits to an async task. If the user submits a clean form (without validation errors) the controller iterates correctly and makes all the correct calls to the various endpoints it needs to do. However, if the user fails to fill in a required field, the controller repeats the actionresult. It doesn't seem to matter how many times someone presses submit with validations it always fires twice.

Here is the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PostCheckoutForm(CheckoutForm checkoutForm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        };

        var basket = await TransactionLibrary.GetBasketAsync();

        switch (checkoutForm.SelectedPayment)
         {
             case PaymentType.Card:
        var restClient = new WorldpayRestClient("https://api.worldpay.com/v1", _config.WorldPayServiceKey);

        try
        {
            var sentToCrm = await _orderService.SaveOpportunity(CreateRequest(basket, checkoutForm));
```

the sentToCrm await task is firing twice creating two opportunities in our CRM but again fires once without any validations issues.

Here is the view:

```
<div class="checkout" data-component="components/checkout" data-checkout-client-id="@Model.ClientId">

            @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<CheckoutPageSurfaceController>("PostCheckoutForm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "checkout__form" }))
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

        <section class="checkout__details">
            <div class="checkout__input-cells">
                <div class="checkout__input-cell">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)*
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
                </div>

<input class="checkout__payment-button button" type="submit" name="process" id="card_payment" value="Submit Payment" onclick='Worldpay.submitTemplateForm()' data-payment-type="@PaymentType.Card" />
```

Here is a snippet of the class for the form

```
public class CheckoutForm
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }


    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name"), Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Any ideas whats causing the issues?

EDIT: Worldpay API action (for on-click):

```
Worldpay.template.submitTemplateForm=function(){
return Worldpay.callbacks.beforeSubmit()?void 
Worldpay.template.sendMessage(Worldpay.helpers.JSON.stringify({
submit:!0})):!1}
```

Comment: What is your `onclick='Worldpay.submitTemplateForm()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke That I believe is the call using WorldPay's API. I've added the snippet from their API - I think its just the method of using the WorldPay form to collect the values

Comment: Not enough info, but it look like you are making an ajax call,but not cancelling the normal form submit, therefore you are submitting twice

Comment: @StephenMuecke Would that only be impacted due to validation? As mentioned it works perfect if all fields are entered correctly

Comment: Not sure (I don't know anything about Worldpay)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Everything is processing fine into WorldPay. My initial thoughts were that the checkoutForm parameter is being populated multiple times but that should then fire for each time validation failes which it doesn't. Also the calls dont fire before the validation is resolved (just referring to you saying its firing twice due to the onclick)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thanks for your guidance. I've worked around this for now by bringing validation into jquery in the view before sending hte form